# Search a string with strstr in a part of an char *

Tags: c, strstr

currently I search a `char *` with `strstr` but I dont want to search in the complete one, only from the 42. char to the end.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: `strstr(haystack + 42, needle)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 42 to the original str pointer (beware that original string length is greater than 42 though):

```
first_occurence = strstr(str + 42, substr);
```

Comment: thanks, is there something like strstr in ansi c for case insensitive comparison?

Comment: @Sebastian: there is `strcasestr()` version, but it is non-standard.

Comment: Thanks it works! Ok I have only problems now with the difference between Ü and ü and such things. (its an UTF8 encoded c string)

Comment: @Sebastian: I'm afraid `strcasestr` doesn't work with UTF-8 string, it can only recognize ASCII. Though you can convert both strings from utf-8 to `wchar_t` using `mbstowcs()` (you may want to `setlocale()` before), bring them `towlower()` and then locate using `wcsstr()`

Answer (score 2):

Just provide `strstr()` with a pointer to the first character to include in the seach:

```
if(strstr(the_haystack + 42, "the needle") != NULL)
  printf("found needle at end of haystack!\n");
```

Of course, this assumes that `the_haystack` really is at least 42 characters long.